# Distribution of PDF Files with Active Content

Tags: .net, pdf, sanitize, pdfa

I have run a security scan on my application.

One of the findings was **Distribution of PDF Files with Active Content**

There is an upload pdf functionality in the application.
I am trying to find a way reject or sanitize these PDF files.

I have found 1 package [sautinsoft.document](https://sautinsoft.com/) that did the job, but it is not open source.

Is there any .NET open source package that can help in this scenario?